# Why is my custom post type shown in the wrong place?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-formats

I'm using a template which shows the post formats pretty nice, but I don't think the WordPress way of making post formats is very user friendly. Therefore I have created my own custom post types by using the plugin Types.

The problem is when I'm posting a custom post, it shows up like a normal post, and not on the some post area as my theme.

My custom post has the URL `/audio`, shown as a archive, while the theme post has the URL `/type/audio`. I have tried different kind of code, changing the menu, and changing the URL for the custom posts, but nothing is really working.

The theme is using this to show the dedicated posts:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying audio post archive page.
 *
 * @package TA Music
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <!-- breadcrumbs -->
    <section id="breadcrumbs" xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#">
        <div class="container">
        <?php ta_breadcrumbs(); ?>
        </div>
    </section><!-- #breadcrumbs -->


    <section id="tagline">
        <div class="container">
            <h1><?php if ( ta_option( 'albums_listing_title' ) != '' ) { echo ta_option( 'albums_listing_title' ); } ?></h1>
            <h4><?php if ( ta_option( 'albums_listing_tagline' ) != '' ) { echo ta_option( 'albums_listing_tagline' ); } ?></h4>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- main content area -->
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <section id="content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 albums-desc">
                        <p><?php if ( ta_option( 'albums_listing_desc' ) != '' ) { echo ta_option( 'albums_listing_desc' ); } ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php
                    if ( have_posts() ) :
                        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                            $post_tags = get_the_tags();
                            if ( $post_tags ) {
                                foreach( $post_tags as $tag ) {
                                    $all_tags_arr[] = $tag -> name;
                                }
                            }
                        endwhile;
                    endif; 

                    $terms = array_unique( $all_tags_arr );
                    $count = count( $terms );

                    if ( $count > 0 && ta_option( 'albums_filter_switch') == '1' ) {
                        echo '<ul class="isotope-filters album-filter">';
                        echo '<li class="current"><a href="#" data-filter="*">'. __( 'All Albums', 'ta-music' ) .'</a></li>';
                            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                $term_name = strtolower( $term );
                                $term_name = str_replace( ' ', '_', $term_name );

                                echo '<li><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i><a href="#" data-filter=".'.$term_name.'">'.$term.'</a></li>';
                            }
                        echo '</ul>';
                    }
                ?>

                <div class="row albums">
                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                    <!-- albums -->
                    <?php
                        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'post_tag' );

                        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
                            $tags = array();

                            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                $tags[] = $term->name;
                            }

                            $tags = str_replace( ' ', '_', $tags );
                            $tax = join( " ", $tags );

                        else :
                            $tax = '';
                        endif;
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 album <?php echo strtolower( $tax ); ?>">
                        <div class="latest-content">
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                                <div class="latest-content-image">
                                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                        the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) );
                                    } ?>
                                </div>

                                <div class="latest-content-info">
                                    <div class="meta">
                                        <div class="icon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-headphones"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                        <p><?php echo strip_tags( get_the_tag_list( '', ', ', '' ) ); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- .latest-content-info -->
                            </a>
                        </div><!-- .latest-content -->
                    </div><!-- .album -->

                    <?php
                        endwhile;

                        else :
                            get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
                        endif;
                    ?>

                </div><!-- .albums -->

                <?php ta_pagination(); ?>

            </div><!-- #container -->
        </section>
    </main><!-- #main -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

How can I make my custom posts show up in the same area, and have the same styling?
Or do you have another idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: "The problem is when i'm posting a custom post, it shows up like a normal post, and not on the some post area as my theme." -- I don't know what that means.

Comment: When i'm posting a custom posts (url: /audio) - the styling looks like a normal post.

But when i'm posting from the template (/type/audio) it has a completly different styling. Eventhough the post has the same format.